# Изменить адрес папки с Python'ом

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, python-3.5, anaconda

Итак, мне нужно изменить адрес папки Python35-32 на моем компьтере.

Я думал переустановить указав новый путь, но мне нужно чтобы библиотеки установленные с помощью

```
pip install package_name
```

остались у меня на компьютере, т.е когда я буду кодить на перестановленной версии, я хочу иметь возможность использовать

```
import package_name
```

Тоже самое требуется сделать для Anaconda3

P.S Я знаю, что можно просто записать все названия и версии моих библиотек и переустановить вручную, но мне нужен способ сделать это быстрее, ибо библиотек очень много

P.S.S Если просто вырезать Python из старой папки и вставить в новую, pip перестанет и все сервисы перестанут работать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб сохранить весь список библиотек выполните команду:

```
pip freeze > all-libs.txt
```

Для переустановки по этому списку выполняете:

```
pip install -r all-libs.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Пути к папке с питоном [прописаны в реестре](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0514/) и в переменной окружения.
Через regedit исправьте пути в ветке `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.5\InstallPath`.
В ветке `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\` нужно править если питон установлен для всех пользователей.

Используйте `msconfig` чтоб поправить переменые окружения и перезагрузите компьютер.